# TYPO3 Exception ExtensionManagementUtility not found

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

i need to use an old installation (TYPO3 8.7.36) to import a bunch of translations via l10nmgr. (Later i will transfer the tables to TYPO3 11). Problem is that the xml file is too big for importing via the backend so i has to use cli.

When i try typo3/sysext/core/bin/typo3 (or ./typo3/cli_dispatch.phpsh) i get the exception:

```
 Uncaught TYPO3 Exception Class "TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility" not found 
 thrown in file /Volumes/web/src/typo3_src-8.7.36/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/GeneralUtility.php
```

in line 3341

Any idea what is happening here? The extension manager ist installed and so is this class ... ?

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a problem with the autoloader. Did you clear the autoload cache (with composer it's `composer dumpautoload`, else in the installtool is a button for it)?